# How to read the output of another process in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I am a c++ guy, new to Linux C. Pls. advice possible solution.

**My Scenario:** There are two process, process A and process B. Process B is a wrapper which will just launch process A and wait for some time and continues its operation.

**Requirement:** I should wait until process A prints **"Ready to Go!"** and then continue with process B's activities.

**What I want to do?** I want to launch process A from process B and check if the output of process A has the `string` which I wanted to wait for and then continue.

Currently I have the code to launch process A and wait for some seconds and then continue with process B.

How can this be achieved in C Linux?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Read up on Interprocess Communication: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html

Comment: This is usually done by opening a pipe, forking, closing unused ends of the pipe from the two processes, then invoking `exec` from the child process.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at **Inter Process Communication** in order to understand the different methods used by processes to communicate with each other. Shared memory or message queue would be good to go with. For starting up `process_A` from `Process_B`, use `exec`. Have a look at [this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/) for reference.